# Socket Programing By C# in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, perl

Is this Possible that write a Socket by C# in ASP.net ? 
for Example Can i write a Code Like this Perl Code in C# and asp.net ? :

```
> use HTTP::Request::Common qw(POST);
> use LWP::UserAgent; $ua = new
> LWP::UserAgent(agent => 'Mozilla/5.0(Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.0.5)Gecko/20060719 Firefox/1.5.0.5'); 
> $ua -> timeout(20);
> my $req = POST 'http://Example.com/',
> [ login_username => 'mehdi' , login22 => '654321' , go => 'submit']; 
> my $content = $ua->request($req);
```

please Give me an example or Convert the above code to C# and asp.net .
Thanks in Advance .

Comment: It's possible, but you'd use the HTTP client, not raw sockets.

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/WebRequestNResponseMDB12012005232323PM/WebRequestNResponseMDB.aspx

Comment: Steven : yes , sorry i said to HTTP client => Socket Programing :d

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you could achieve the same functionality in .NET using the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/5.0(Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.0.5)Gecko/20060719 Firefox/1.5.0.5";
            var values = new NameValueCollection
            {
                { "login_username", "mehdi" },
                { "login22", "654321" },
                { "go", "submit" }
            };
            var result = client.UploadValues("http://example.com", values);

            // TODO: handle the result here like
            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.Default.GetString(result));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Darin Dimitrov , very nice answer

Comment: what is the namespace of "NameValueCollection" and Encoding.Default.GetString ? Tnx

Comment: `System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection` and `System.Text.Encoding`. `Shift+Alt+F10+Enter` on the red squiggle and Visual Studio will take care.